# How to disable CSS transitions, update styles, and then restore transitions quickly with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I'm building a CSS and JavaScript clock which uses `transform: rotate(xdeg)` to rotate the clock hands. The CSS `transition` property is used to smooth each hand rotation and simulate a real clock. The hands are divs absolutely positioned at `top: 50%` and `left: 50%` to start, and are rotated -90 degrees when pointed towards 12 o'clock.

So the full cycle for the seconds hand is to increment 6 degrees every second, going from -90 degrees to 264 degrees, then back to -90 degrees. The problem is that the transition applied to the hands makes the hand go backwards around the clock when going from 264 degrees to -90 degrees (59 seconds to 0 seconds).

I've tried checking for when the seconds hand is at 59 seconds (`transform: rotate(264deg)`), temporarily disabling the transition by setting a `no-transition` class on the element, changing the `transform` property to `rotate(-96deg`) which is identical to `rotate(264deg)` in terms of how it looks, then removing the `no-transition` class. This should smooth the transition because then the rotation goes from -96deg to -90 deg. See code below.

JavaScript:

```
const secondsHand = document.querySelector('.seconds-hand');

function setTime(){
    const now = new Date();
    const seconds = now.getSeconds();

    let secondsDegrees = ((seconds / 60) * 360) - 90;
    secondsHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg)`;

    if(seconds === 59){
        secondsDegrees = -96;
        secondsHand.classList.add('no-transition');
        secondsHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsDegrees})`;
        secondsHand.classList.remove('no-transition');
    }

// Code to handle other hands of the clock goes here

}
```

CSS:

```css
.no-transition {
    transition: none !important;
}
```

This does not work unfortunately. Here's a codepen of the problem: https://codepen.io/tillytoby/pen/axRByw

Comment: Have you considered setting it to rotate to 270deg and then immediately disabling the transition and resetting it back to -90deg before enabling the transition and allowing it to continue?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code i can see you add a class 'no-transition' and then remove it. The removal should be made like 'n' seconds before. You can achieve that by using setInterval. Check:

```
if(seconds === 59){
    secondsDegrees = -96;
    secondsHand.classList.add('no-transition');
    secondsHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg)`;
    //1000 is the delay, in this case 1000 miliseconds.
    setTimeout( function () {secondsHand.classList.remove('no-transition');},1000)
}
```

Comment: This works, but it's not ideal. The transition effect is removed between 59 and 0 seconds. I'd like for the transition to still work.